# playonlinux installation error

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I was trying to install playonlinux on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit, so that I could install adobe ps cc. I have already installed wine from the software center, but I got some errors, here I am attaching the snap.

---

[1st snap of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k689U.png)

---

[Continuation of snap1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMYrd.png)

---

Talking about the last few lines in second image, "errors were encountered while processing:"

1. runit
2. git-daemon-run

---

These are the errors I get after I try to install any application on ubuntu. How ca I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you get these errors while installing _any_ application? (also, from time to time is good to run `apt-get autoremove`)

Comment: Any errors when you run  "sudo dpkg --configure -a"

Comment: @luchonach Yeah the runit and git-daemon error, I get this everytime.
Ad what does apt-get autoremove do?

Comment: @DneDevil I would be happy to tell you the output of sudo dpkg --configure -a as soon as I switch to Ubuntu, currently I am working on windows.

Comment: @DnrDevil Yes when I run the command there is an error, it says failed to connect to socket/com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused.
Here is the snap of the error: http://i64.tinypic.com/2iqdl0.png

Comment: @DnrDevil When I am using sudo dpkg -r runit I get this error:

Comment: @DnrDevil http://i68.tinypic.com/35hkda8.png

Comment: Yea i figured you might nees to force it but worth a try updated answer

Comment: @DnrDevil Not helping, it says dpkg status database is locked by another process.   http://i68.tinypic.com/2lcwr2o.png

Comment: Can you update the question  with: sudo lsof

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36376/discussion-between-prateek-coder-and-dnrdevil).

Answer (score 0):

You cant run dpkg and need to unlock it.

Try using

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

(This will probably tell you to run dpkg)
If not run updates with

```
sudo update-manager
```

If it does run

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

This will unlock dpkg
Next run updates using

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then reboot your computer

```
sudo reboot
```

After you have rebooted reopen the terminal and clean old pakages

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Hopefully theses steps will also fix

```
runit
```

If not run:

```
sudo apt-get purge git-daemon-run
```

Then:

```
sudo dpkg -r runit
```